# Poetry installation with Windows WSL not working, ignoring $HOME

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, wsl-2, python-poetry

I have a WSL instance, Ubuntu 20.04 and I have created another Ubuntu 18.04 WSL instance.

I installed Poetry on the 20.04 without issues.

I am trying to install Poetry on the Ubuntu 18.04 instance, using the `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python3 -` command.

At the moment, my $HOME env var points to `/home/fromzeroedu`.

However, after installation, Poetry is installed on my Windows user home:

```
$ which poetry
/mnt/c/Users/j/.poetry/bin/poetry
```

And if I try getting the version, I get:

```
$ poetry --version
/usr/bin/env: ‘python\r’: Permission denied
```

I even tried setting the `POETRY_HOME` prior to installation:

```
export POETRY_HOME=/home/fromzeroedu/.poetry/bin/poetry
```

But Poetry still installs in the Windows user directory.

Sometimes I love Poetry...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That was because bash didn't knew where to look for the bin so it found only the Windows executable (`PATH` is shared between *wsl* and *windows*)

to solve it you needed to add the following to your `~/.bashrc` (preferably on top)

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"
```

With the new installer (poetry **1.1.7** onward) the Bin path changed

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

I faced this issue cause I'm using autocomplete [plugin](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#enable-tab-completion-for-bash-fish-or-zsh) for *oh-my-zsh* and poetry needs to be added to `PATH` before the plugin is loaded. but the installation script append it at the end.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this. One minor edit: the two `bashrc` paths above look the same to me?

Comment: thanks for notifying me, I've corrected it.